# Portal 2 Authoring tools problem

Tags: technical-issues, portal-2

I have a problem getting the Portal 2 Authoring tools to run.

Since I didn't have any storage space on drive C I moved the game (Portal2) to drive F and re installed Portal2 Auth. tools. The game works fine, but when I try to start Auth tools it says :

```
    Setup file  gameinfo.txt dosent exists on subdirectory 
    C:/Steam/steamapps/common/Portal 2/portal2  
check your game parameter or VCONFIG Setting
```

But the game isn't in drive C! What can I do?

I already did:

- Unistall Auth tools
- Remove the Auth tools .acf
- Remove Auth tools downloading file
- Reinstall Auth tools

None of it worked

Answer (score 3):

The fix for me was to go to `F:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Portal 2\bin` and modify the file `GameConfig.txt`

It contains something like  `"GameDir"      "C:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Portal 2\portal2"`

Change `C:\<Old Drive>` to `F:\<New Drive>`.  Also do same thing for `"BSP"`  `"Vis"` ... and any other Data that defines a path.